# Groovy Expression evaluation

Tags: groovy

A basic groovy question. In order to make my code robust, I need to make use of Eval.me(String) that groovy offers.

I have a problem though.It arises when I try to do string comparison.

```
def x='yay'
def y='yay'
def groovyString="'$x' == '$y'"
println Eval.me(groovyString);
```

This prints true.

But the below code just says 'yay' is not a variable definition,

```
def x='yay'
def y='yay'
def groovyString="$x == $y"
println Eval.me(groovyString);
```

I am aware as to why this error is coming :) Is there a way where i can sidestep this issue w/o actually needing to append `' '` for string comparisions??

P.S:I need it to work properly for more than just strings. Hence the apprehension to append ' '

Comment: The problem with the second one is you are executing a groovy expression within groovy so the $x and $y get evaluated in the script as normal GString and subsitute the word yay into your string BEFORE its sent to the GroovyShell.  You'd need to escape the expression (ie \$x) .  Then adding the binding `new Binding( [x: x, y: y])`.  If you were reading the groovy script external to the code, say like a file this wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a `Binding` and `GroovyShell`

If we make an instance of GroovyShell with a Binding that by default returns the name of the property when no property s found:

```
def shell = new GroovyShell( new Binding( [:].withDefault{ it } ) )
```

We can then evaluate your groovyString:

```
shell.evaluate( groovyString )
```

Which basically evaluates to the first form, as both `yay` properties get resolved to the String `yay`

Comment: Obviously if you need to pass params, then you can change `[:].withDefault { it }` to something like `[ a: 13 ].withDefault { it }`.  Then `groovyString = 'a == 13'` will work for example...  Good luck!